# Laravel 8 eloquent relationship filtering

Tags: laravel, eloquent-relationship, php-8.2

I would like to achieve something like this:

```
$queryResult = WebsiteShareDynamic::with([
    'websiteRevenue' => function($query) { 
        $query->whereColumn('website_revenue.date', 'website_shares_dynamic.date'); 
    }, 
    'websiteMeasure' => function($query) { 
        $query->whereColumn('website_measure.date', 'website_shares_dynamic.date'); 
    }
])
->whereIn('website_shares_dynamic.id', $maxWSD)
->orderBy('website_shares_dynamic.date', 'DESC')
->get();
```

Without the filter in the with I get 800 websiteRevenue and websiteMeasure and I only want the ones that the column 'date' matches the one in WebsiteShareDynamic.

The relations look like this:

```
public function websiteRevenue(){
    return $this->hasMany(WebsiteRevenue::class, 'website_id', 'website_id');
}

public function websiteMeasure(){
    return $this->hasMany(WebsiteMeasure::class, 'website_id', 'website_id');
}
```

I'm just looking for an alternative instead of joining tables, since the performance is way too slow with the joins.

Thanks in advance.

I've tried to use the whereHas clause to achieve the mentioned behavior but without success.

Comment: You've got 2 issues here; 1) `with()` doesn't perform any kind of join, so `website_shares_dynamic.date` is not available there. You'd need to do `->join(...)` and manually join the tables. 2) `where()` performs a string comparison, not a column comparison. You'd need to use `->whereColumn()`. Your query is currently performing `WHERE website_revenue.date = 'website_shares_dynamic.date'` (notice the `'` around `'table.column'`?) That is a very different query than `WHERE website_revenue.date = website_shares_dynamic.date` (lack of quotes denotes it's a column).

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply Tim, fixed the code with your corrections, joining the tables makes it take way more. I was wondering if there would be a way to filter the eloquent relation on the go to avoid having the 800 relations.. Do you have any idea of how to achieve something similar to what I intended? Thanks.

Comment: No problem! Unfortunately I can't speak to performance; my expertise is with Laravel, and I'm not an SQL expert in that sense. If you add the appropriate SQL tag to your question (`mysql`, `postgres`, etc.) you might attract an expert who can help with some techniques (indexing, subqueries, something else?), but it might also mean you have to use a non-Laravel solution (i.e. something like `DB::select(...)` or `DB::raw(...)`, etc.)